# How to get a node using index

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have an entity Place:

```
@NodeEntity
@TypeAlias(value="Place")
public class Place  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @GraphId 
    private Long nodeId;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String id;

        //...
}
```

And I try to get a node based on its id attribute this way:

```
String pfc = "1234";
(Node)template.getIndex(Place.class, "id").get("id", pfc).getSingle()
```

But I'm having this exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Index name for class java.lang.String id rel: false idx: true must differ from the default name: Place
```

Must I necessairly add a name to the  index?
If yes, how should I do for the existent data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version are you using? In SDN 3.x for Neo4j 2.x the indexes and constraints are used automatically.

I would use a `PlaceRepository` with a `findById()` method.

Or in general cypher queries that access place *like* this:

```
MATCH (p:Place {id:{id}})-->(x)
RETURN x
```

You can access them manually with `template.merge()` or `template.findByLabelAndProperty()` which I would only recommend when you know what you're doing.